# How to access private properties from an IFFE in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was playing with the idea of using an IFFE inside a object declaration instead of an init() method that I have to manually invoke at the end of the declaration. The only problem I seem to be having is that I don't know how to access private properties from within the IFFE. Take the following example:

```
function Obj() {

    this.prop = 'Public property';
    var _prop = 'Private property';

    ( function( that ) {

        console.log( that.prop );
        console.log( that._prop ); // Returns undefined

    } )( this );

}

obj = new Obj();
```

by passing `this` into the IFFE I can access the `this` scope but the private properties do not seem to be assessable through this. I know I could manually pass individual properties in, but I would prefer a solution that allows me access to all private properties.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: what does `console.log(_prop)` give you?

Comment: *"but the private properties do not seem to be assessable through `this`"*  That's the whole point. If you could access them via `this`, then everyone who has a reference to the object could (in fact, you are doing that with `this.prop`). "Private properties" are nothing else but local variables. How do you access variables?

Comment: It's a variable. There's no such thing as a "private property" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**IIFE** is the way as the **Module Pattern** is implemented. (See [The Module Pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/))

Any object declared inside a function is isolated from the outer scope, maning that ***private variables*** are **unaccessible**. If you need to modify private objects, you can reconsider using an **IIFE**.

Now take a look at your code, the variable `_prop` is declared in the same **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)** where the **IFFE** is defined, meaning that you can access that object within the **IIFE**, e.g.

```
function Obj() {
    var _private = 1;

    //IIFE
    (function() {
        console.log("_private: ", _private);
    }());
}
```

Also, you may create a public method that modifies the private object, e.g.

```
function Obj() {
    var _seed = 0;
    this.setSeed = function (seed) {
        _seed = seed;
    };
    this.getSeed = function() {
        return _seed;
    };
}
```

Or you can define a **getter / setter** in the instance **prototype**, but this approach has the disadvantage to have a lower performance, e.g.

```
function Obj() {
    var _seed = 0;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "seed", {
        get: function () { return _seed; },
        set: function (seed) {
            //ensure to be a numeric value
            if (+seed || seed === 0) _seed = +seed;
        }
    });
}
```

Or creating a **module** with **[loose augmentation](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)**

```
//begin IIFE
var module = (function (module) {
    var _private = 1;

    function getPrivate() {
        return _private;
    }

    function setPrivate(value) {
        _private = value;
    }

    function printPublicMember() {
        console.log(module.publicMember);
    }

    //public mudule API
    module = {
        "publicMember": "I am public!!",
        "printPublicMember": printPublicMember,
        "getPrivate": getPrivate,
        "setPrivate": setPrivate
    };

    return module;

}(window.module || {}));
//end IIFE
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jherax said the purpose of using an IFFE is to approximate block level scope in JavaScript so accessing a private property outside of an IFFE defeats the purpose of having one.

However you could create an API of sorts by returning an object which points to the properties in question. Used improperly this is a bit of a hack and is generally discouraged.

```
function Obj() {

this.prop = 'Public property';
var _prop = 'Private property';

  ( function( that ) {

    console.log( that.prop );
    console.log( that._prop ); // Returns undefined

  } )( this );
  return {
    accessPoint: _prop //gives you a getter of sorts to _prop
  };
}

obj = new Obj();
obj.accessPoint;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because:

```
var _prop = 'Private property';
```

creates a local variable and

```
    console.log( that._prop ); // Returns undefined
```

is attempting to access the `_prop` property of *that* (aka *this*). Variables are not object properties*. Use:

```
    console.log( _prop ); // Returns Private property
```

- Well, variables are properties of a [*VariableEnvironment*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) which belongs to a [*LexicalEnvironment*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3), a kind of object (in ECMA-262 ed 3 it was called a [*variable object*](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3)) but you can't access those directly in the way you can access variables as properties of the *global* or *window* object.

Answer (score 0):

The IIFE inside your constructor has no meaning whatsoever. It is exactly equivalent to just writing its contents directly. The purpose of an IIFE is to create an enclosed scope with local variables, which you don't have.

In what way is this IFFE supposed to avoid having to call some `init` function? The constructor is already an `init` function in its own way.

The reason you can't access `that._prop` from within your IIFE is that there is no instance property called `_prop`. There is a local variable called `_prop`, To access it, simply say `_prop`, not `this._prop` or `that._prop`.

Comment: I wrote this question quite a while ago. I was still coming to terms with how scope worked nested functions. Agreed that this particular function does nothing important as no variables are declared. That was probably because I heavily simplified the example to try help me grasp what I wasn't understanding. Thanks for your response.